# Find if the first tree is a subset of the second tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, subtree

I checked all around the internet to find out how to check if a tree is a subSet of another. By subset, I mean The `issubset` function should `return 1` if all the elements of the first tree appear in the second tree
and `0` otherwise. Note that depending on the insertion order of elements, two trees with same set of elements can have very different shapes. Given the following examples as trees:

```
Elements of the first tree
             4
           /  \
         2     6
        / \   / \
       1   2  5  7 


Elements of the second Tree
            6
          /   \
         4     7
        /  \
       2    5
      / \
     1   2
```

The following code traverses the trees then checks the values:

```
int issubset(nodeT **tree1, nodeT **tree2) {

    if( *tree2 == NULL)
        return TRUE;
    if(*tree1 == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    if(are_identical(&(*tree1),&(*tree2)))
        return TRUE;

    return issubset(&(*tree1)->pLeft, &(*tree2)) || issubset(&(*tree2)->pRight, &(*tree2));
}

int are_identical(nodeT **tree1, nodeT **tree2) {
    nodeT **temp;
    int iFound = 0, i, r;   
    if( *tree2 == NULL)
        return TRUE;

    if( (*tree1) ==NULL && (*tree2) ==NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if( (*tree1)->iValue != (*tree2)->iValue) {
        if(iFound = 0)
            return TRUE;

        i = issubset(&(*tree1)->pLeft, &(*tree2));
        if( i ==0) {
            r = issubset(&(*tree1)->pRight, &(*tree2));
            return r;
        }

        return i;
    }   

    return((*tree1)->iValue == (*tree2)->iValue && are_identical(&(*tree1)->pLeft, &(*tree2)->pLeft) && 
           are_identical(&(*tree1)->pRight, &(*tree2)->pRight) );
}
```

After running my code with the given examples, my output gives back that the first tree is not a subset of the second, when it actually is a subset.

Comment: The first tree is not a subtree of the second, because it has a different topology.  Do you mean to check that the elements of the first tree are a subset of the elements of the second?

Comment: @augura i Had modify the trees picture

Comment: @EduardoJuarez  Still wrong.  4 and 5 are adjacent in the second tree but not the first.

Comment: You are right. I had edited my tags

Comment: I had edited my question . @augurar

Comment: Please define what you mean by "subset". *A set is a well defined collection of distinct objects.* - your trees do not have distinct members.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I had done more editing. I hope it is well explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I still try to give you my answer. From your example I assume that you're working with binary search trees. But I do not know what kind of binary tree you're using, I will assume a general scheme. I guess if the tree is somewhat balanced then maybe you can get a better algorithm.

Since you have binary search trees, you could assume a function `search(root, key)` which returns a valid pointer to a node containing `key` if this one is found or `NULL` otherwise.

Also, I assume that you know the numbers of nodes of each tree. So you could return `0` if `tree1` has lesser nodes than `tree`. Otherwise the approach is as follows:

```
int tree1_contained_in_tree2(node * tree1, node * tree2)
{
  if (tree1 == NULL) // am I visiting a empty tree?
    return 1;

  // so I am sure tree1 is not NULL ==> I search the contained key in tree2
  if (search(tree2, tree1->key) == NULL)
    return 0; // tree1->key does not belong to tree2

  // here tree1->key belongs to tree1 so, I test with the subtrees of root
  return tree1_contained_in_tree2(tree1->left, tree2) && 
         tree1_contained_in_tree2(tree1->right, tree2);    
}
```

I prefer to use simple pointers to nodes instead of double pointers. I think you can adapt my approach to yours.

The algorithm is `O(n log m)` if `tree2` is balanced (`O(n m)` otherwise) where `n` is the number of nodes of `tree1` and `m` the number of nodes of `tree2`

Comment: @irleon Your implementations is correct! I totally forgot about searchT. Indeed, using double points is tedious, but I see double points entertaining.

Comment: If `tree2` is not balanced then this could be worst case `O(nm)`.

Comment: Also you may need to modify this slightly to take duplicate elements into account if your trees permit them.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search trees support efficient sorted iteration over the elements.  Maintain an iterator over the elements of each tree in nondecreasing order.  Repeat the following until a result is determined:

- If the first iterator has no more elements, return `TRUE`.
- If the second iterator has no more elements, return `FALSE`.
- If the current element of the first iterator is less than that of the second, return `FALSE`.
- If the current element of the first iterator is equal to that of the second, update both iterators.
- If the current element of the first tree is greater than that of the second, update the second iterator. (You can optimize this by skipping some elements.)

The basic implementation is worst case `O(n + m)` where `n` and `m` are the respective sizes of the two trees.  With the optimization mentioned you can additionally bound this by `O(n log m)` if the larger tree is balanced, which is useful if the second tree is much larger than the first.  (Whether or not the trees are balanced, the `O(n + m)` bound still applies.)

Comment: While this answer is correct for binary search trees (BSTs), his trees are not BSTs since they don't contain distinct members - two 2's.

Comment: @JonnyHenly This algorithm works for any data structure that supports sorted iteration.  This will check that the larger collection has at least as many copies of each element as the smaller.